# How to save file locally and save path on database using multer on angular

Tags: node.js, angular, angular6, mean-stack, multer

I have a form that asks for details of pdf file in Angular. I want to upload that file to **PDFS** folder, not to the database. So here I want to do three things :

1. How to rename filename using users title with extension pdf
2. How to save that file in PDFs folder
3. How to save path of that file which we have saved in the database.

**tech: Angular, express, MongoDB, multer**

You can provide me a link if any example is already available with all these conditions.

Answer (score 0):

This is the express node and mongo end to save file to the folder locally in your express server. The path will

```
    const multer = require('multer');
    const path = require('path');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const DIR = path.join(__dirname, '../PDFS/');
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: (req, file, cb) => {
            cb(null, DIR);
        },
        filename: (req, file, cb) => {
          // implement getLoggedInUser() method which basically returns the current logged in user
             cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now()+ getLoggedInUser())
        },
    });
    //upload end point
    app.post('/upload', upload.array('uploads[]', 12), (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.files);


        if (req.files.length <= 0) {
            res.status(404).send({ message: 'no file recieved' });
        } else {
         fs.readdirSync(DIR).forEach((file)=>{

         let path=path.join(DIR,file);
         let fileSchema= new FileSchema(path);
         fileSchema.save((err,result)=>{
           if (err) {
             throw new Error({ message: 'user is not saved', status: 500 });
           }
          res.status(200).send({ message: 'file successfully saved' });
         });
       });
     }
    });
```

From your angular application you can create a service and inject it inside your form component

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http'
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UploadService {
  static API_URL: string = '<url for your upload end point>';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  fileUpload(files: any): Observable<Object> {
    const formData: any = new FormData();
    const fileArray: Array<File> = files;
    for (let i = 0; i < fileArray.length; i++) {
      formData.append('uploads[]', fileArray[i], fileArray[i]['name']);
    }
    return this.http.post(UploadService.API_URL + 'upload', formData)
      .pipe(
        map(x => {
          return x;
        })
      );
  }
}
```